# Get bits from a ByteBuffer

Tags: java, bit

I am working on a BitBuffer that will take x bits from a ByteBuffer as an int, long, etc, but I seem to be having a whole lot of problems.

I've tried loading a long at a time and using bit shifting, but the difficulty comes from rolling from one long into the next. I am wondering if there's just a better way. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
public class BitBuffer 
{
    final private ByteBuffer bb;

    public BitBuffer(byte[] bytes) 
    {       
        this.bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
    }

    public int takeInt(int bits) 
    {
        int bytes = toBytes(bits);
        if (bytes > 4) throw new RuntimeException("Too many bits requested");

        int i=0;
        // take bits from bb and fill it into an int
        return i;
    }
}
```

More specifically, I am trying to take x bits from the buffer and return them as an int (the minimal case). I can access bytes from the buffer, but let's say I only want to take just the first 4 bits instead.

Example:

If my buffer is filled with "101100001111", if I run these in order:

```
takeInt(4) // should return 11    (1011)
takeInt(2) // should return 0     (00)
takeInt(2) // should return 0     (00)
takeInt(1) // should return 1     (1)
takeInt(3) // should return 7     (111)
```

I would like to use something like this for bit packed encoded data where an integer can be stored in just a few bits of a byte.

Comment: Check `ImageInputStream` implementations from a JDK, like https://github.com/frohoff/jdk7u/tree/master/src/share/classes/javax/imageio/stream for inspiration.

Comment: Better way than what?  You haven’t shown how you’re doing it, beyond a one-line comment in the code.

Comment: You need to better describe your issue.  We can guess at existing Python code that might help you, as @matanper did, but it really is just guessing.  Until we know what you really are trying to do, it's hard to give you a reasonable answer.  You should put more of your own code showing what you've tried .  Also, what would be really good would be to give us the input and output that you want.

Comment: Please review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - If you can, it would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I thought it was pretty simple to understand -- return an int by taking bits from a buffer at a time... but I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

The BitSet and ByteBuffer ideas were a bit too difficult to control so instead, I went with a binary string approach that basically takes a whole lot of headache out of managing an intermediate buffer of bits.

```
public class BitBuffer 
{
    final private String bin;
    private int start;

    public BitBuffer(byte[] bytes) 
    {       
        this.bin = toBinaryString(bytes); // TODO: create this function
        this.start = 0;
    }

    public int takeInt(int nbits) 
    {
        // TODO: handle edge cases
        String bits = bin.substring(start, start+=nbits);
        return Integer.parseInt(bits, 2);
    }
}
```

Out of everything I've tried this was the cleanest and easiest approach, but I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the `ByteBuffer` into `BitSet` and then you'll have continuous access to the bits

```java
public class BitBuffer 
{
    final private BitSet bs;

    public BitBuffer(byte[] bytes) 
    {       
        this.bs = BitSet.valueOf(bytes);
    }

    public int takeInt(int bits) 
    {
        int bytes = toBytes(bits);
        if (bytes > 4) throw new RuntimeException("Too many bits requested");

        int i=0;
        // take bits from bs and fill it into an int
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish BitSet was more dynamic, but it's purpose is more so to find which bits are set/unset than mangling the bits into another object which is what I am doing.

Comment: Well, `BitSet` have get(start Index, endIndex), and toString, which does exactly what you posted in your answer. Performance wise I don't know if one is preferred over the another, but memory wise the bitset is more compact